# Passing Data from one element to another in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm going through some of the classic ToDo examples but can't find quite what I'm looking for.  I have a 'right-part' and a 'left-part' div which are sitting side by side.  In the 'left-part' I have the todo list names displayed like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: taskLists()"> // runs through all todo lists
    <li><span data-bind="text: title"></span></li>//displays list title                          
</ul>
```

On click, I would like to change the contents of the 'right-part' to display the information for the current list.  Would look something like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: title"></span> // title of current list
<ul data-bind="foreach: items"> // runs through all items in current list
    <li data-bind="title"> //displays item title
</ul>
```

I'm not sure what the best strategy is for passing the specific list on the left side to the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking about this the wrong way. You don't pass data from one div to another, you have a view model and the divs will display the state of your view model.

So, if you have one collection in your VM:

```
self.taskList = ko.observableArray();
```

What you might do is add a property for the selected item

```
self.selected = ko.observable();
```

And then add a click handler to select an item from the tasklist and put it in your `selected` property

```
self.selectItem = function(item) {
    self.selected(item);
}
```

And now your binding might look something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: taskLists()"> // runs through all todo lists
    <li data-bind="click: $parent.selectItem"><span data-bind="text: title"></span></li>//displays list title                          
</ul>
```

and:

```
<!-- with: selectedItem -->
<span data-bind="text: title"></span>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items"> // runs through all items in current list
    <li data-bind="title"> //displays item title
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

So now clicking an item in your first div will update the view model by changing the `selected` property and knockout will recognize that the property is bound to the second div and update it too.

Comment: Many thanks, still trying to wrap my head around all this.  I figured it would be something simple, but I just couldn't come up with it!

Answer (score 0):

you should have another **observable** binded to your right panel . then with a click handler ,you add selected list to your right-panel observable and as a result your right panel element got updated . this is binding and what knockoutJs is being used for.

```
 self.rightList = ko.observable();

 // click handler
 self.addToRightList = function(list){
     self.rightList(list);
 }
```

and

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: taskLists()"> // runs through all todo lists
    <li><span data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.addToRightList"></span></li>//displays list title                          
</ul>
```

and

```
  <div data-bind="with: rightList">
     <span data-bind="text: title"></span> // title of current list
     <ul data-bind="foreach: items"> // runs through all items in current list
        <li data-bind="title"> //displays item title
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, still trying to wrap my head around all this.  I figured it would be something simple, but I just couldn't come up with it!